# Disk Usage Analyzer Shows 100% After Expanding VMWare Hard Disk

Tags: linux-mint, partition, vmware, fdisk

I expanded my Hard Disk on my VMWare for this machine to 80GB, installed GParted and expanded the partition.

[image]

But Disk Analyzer is still showing 100% usage.

[image]

When I run `fdisk -l` the output is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Disk model: VMware Virtual S
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6FD5C76D-348F-4810-A0CC-AFD4737E7BA3

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096   1054719   1050624  513M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1054720 167770111 166715392 79.5G Linux filesystem
```

I ran cfdisk and chose /dev/sda3 then Resize and then Write, but Disk Analyzer is still showing 100% usage. Tried a few other solutions as well. Feel like I'm missing something obvious. The partitions all look good in cdisk
[image]

It seems that it is recognizing the extra space, but for some reason it is not associating it with the root directory. I have rebooted several times as well as run

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda3
```

EDIT: Output of df

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs             398320     1664    396656   1% /run
/dev/sda3       81861440 12302772  66003776  16% /
tmpfs            1991592        0   1991592   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda2         524252     5364    518888   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs             398316      124    398192   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Disk Analyzer bugged? ;-) What's the `df` output? Even Gparted shows 66GB free ;-)

Comment: Just added the output. This all started when I was trying to download a massive file and it gave me a warning about space, which it indeed did not have enough. I'll rerun it now and update if I get the error again. Any idea how I might correct disk analyzer?

Comment: UPDATE: Been running smooth downloading 44.17GB. Looks like you were right Disk Usage Analyzer is being buggy.

Comment: `df` shows ~64GB free :-)